# Scatter a dictionary in python using MPI

Tags: python, numpy, mpi, mpi4py

I am fairly new to the world of python and MPI. I am looking at the scatter method and wondering if it is possible to scatter a dictionary.

I have worked with integers and other data types but since, a dictionary can contain anything I am not sure if it can be scattered as a numpy object. Below is what I have tried but it is obviously not working. I do not know how to scatter 'data' even if it is possible as data is a dictionary.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

#data = None
data = {'a': 7,'b': 3.14}
if rank == 0:
   data = np.linspace(1,size) #this is wrong...how do I scatter a dictionary

recvbuf = np.empty(data,dtype=None)
print  comm.Scatter(data, recvbuf, root=0)

print "Rank: ",rank," recvbuf received:",recvbuf
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of mpi4py:

> It supports point-to-point (sends, receives) and collective
>   (broadcasts, scatters, gathers) communications of any picklable Python
>   object, as well as optimized communications of Python object exposing
>   the single-segment buffer interface (NumPy arrays, builtin
>   bytes/string/array objects)

The methods for the pickable python objects (such as dictionaries) are not the same for the objects exposing a single-segment buffer interface. You have to work either with the former or the latter family of method.

In your case, I suppose you want to scatter the dictionary as a couple of key/value. The following does not work as you may expect as only the dictionary keys are scattered:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import OrderedDict
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    data = OrderedDict({'a': 7, 'b': 3.14})
else:
    data = None

data = comm.scatter(data, root=0)

data_type = type(data)
print(f'Data is {data} on rank {rank} with type {data_type}')

# Output
# Data is a on rank 0 with type <class 'str'>
# Data is b on rank 1 with type <class 'str'>
```

In your case, the best approach seems to create a list of dictionaries and to scatter it:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import OrderedDict
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    data = [{'a': 7}, {'b': 3.14}]
else:
    data = None

data = comm.scatter(data, root=0)

data_type = type(data)
print(f'Data is {data} on rank {rank} with type {data_type}')

# Output:
# Data is {'a': 7} on rank 0 with type <class 'dict'>
# Data is {'b': 3.14} on rank 1 with type <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Have a look into dask, which supports distributed data sets. This seems to be what you want.